# emacs installation broke my apt and dpkg system

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, emacs

I messed around with emacs installation some weeks ago, now I cannot install other packages anymore using `dpkg`

for example

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
```

gives me

```
>>Error occurred processing *.el: File error (("Opening input file" "No such file 
or directory" "/usr/share/emacs25/site-lisp/elpa/magit-popup-2.11.0/*.el"))
ERROR: install script from elpa-magit-popup package failed
dpkg: error processing package emacs25-nox (--configure):
 installed emacs25-nox package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of emacs-nox:
 emacs-nox depends on emacs25-nox; however:
  Package emacs25-nox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package emacs-nox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs25-nox
 emacs-nox
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

which seems unrelated to the install task.

Doing `sudo apt --fix-broken install` gives me

```
>>Error occurred processing *.el: File error (("Opening input file" "No such file or directory" "/usr/share/emacs25/site-lisp/elpa/magit-popup-2.11.0/*.el"))
ERROR: install script from elpa-magit-popup package failed
dpkg: error processing package emacs25-nox (--configure):
 installed emacs25-nox package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of emacs-nox:
 emacs-nox depends on emacs25-nox; however:
  Package emacs25-nox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package emacs-nox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs25-nox
 emacs-nox
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`apt autoremve` didn't help either. I'm running out of ideas.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Context:

- I guess I did the big mistake of installing a non-apt version of emacs along with the system's default emacs25 (because I couldn't get magit to work), this is were things started to break everything.
- my system: Ubuntu 18.04

**Update**
commentor 1: how did I install emacs?
I'm not sure anymore how I installed emacs using dpkg. I assume I downloaded a deb file from somewhere and installed it. In bash history I can find

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25-common_25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+18.04_all.deb
sudo dpkg -r emacs
sudo dpkg -r emacs-nox
sudo dpkg -r emacs25-*
sudo dpkg -r emacs25-bin-common 
sudo dpkg -r emacs25-nox
sudo dpkg -r emacs25-bin-common 
sudo dpkg -r elpa-dash
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends emacs
sudo dpkg --purge emacs
sudo dpkg -r --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25-common_25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+18.04_all.deb
```

I also did `apt autoremove` a couple of times

locate *.deb finds

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25-bin-common_25.2+1-6_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25-common_25.2+1-6_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25-el_25.2+1-6_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25_25.2+1-6_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs_47.0_all.deb
```

Comment: Please edit your question to give details about how you installed it.

Comment: You could try to purge the emacs packages, manually clean up your non-apt installation and then install again.

Comment: @mcExchange I can see that you have deleted the answer you provided to your question. Is there a specific reason for that (for example, you later found out that it didn't work)? Because otherwise it should be undeleted as it seems helpful.

Comment: Yes, I still have issues scratching emacs entirely from my system. At first I could `dpkg remove ` emacs packages then `apt remove ` emacs packages. After that apt was working in the sense that I could install another package not related to emacs (`apt-transport-https` ) as mentioned in the question. However trying to reinstall emacs via apt brought back the error mentioned in the question, so I was not able to cleanly remove emacs after all. I updated my question with some more context therefore and leave it open until I get a solution to fully repair my apt + emacs config

Comment: I have the same problem, from a fresh install of 22.04 I installed a bunch of common stuff, including "sudo apt install emacs", and because of an error from the post-installation-script of emacs-gtk, it's stuck, I don't know how to get out